# In golang json.Unmarshal() works in playground/copy pasted JSON but not in actual code

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am writing a program in Golang that interfaces with a modified version of the [barefoot](https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot) mapmatching library which returns results in json via netcat.

My in my actual code `json.Unmarshal` will only parse the response to the nil value of the struct. But if print the json to console (see code snippet below) and [copy paste into goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/GapXP59kr-n) it behaves as expected.

I am wondering if this is an encoding issue that is bypassed when I copy paste from the console as a result.

How do I get my code to process the same string as it is received from barefoot as when it is copy pasted from the console?

Here is the relevant code snippet (structs are identical to goplayground)

```
body := io_func(conn, cmd)
    var obvs []Json_out
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &obvs)
    fmt.Println(body)
    fmt.Println(obvs)
```

and `io_func()` if relevant (the response is two lines, with a message on the first and a json string on the second)

```
func io_func(conn net.Conn, cmd string) string {
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, cmd+"\n")
    r := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    header, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    if header == "SUCCESS\n" {
        resp, _ := r.ReadString('\n')
    return resp
    } else {
        return ""
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Cerise Limón's advice to properly handle error messages I determined the `osm_id` value in the JSON was being parsed by `json.Unmarshall` as number when taking the string from `io_func()`, although it wasn't doing so when the string was passed in manually in the playground example. Although I don't understand why this is so I would have picked it up with proper error handling.

I altered barefoot code to return the `osm_id` explicitly in inverted commas since, although only ever composed of digits, I only use it as a string. It now works as expected. Equally I could have changed the type in the struct and convert in Go as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The io_func function creates and discards a bufio.Reader and data the reader may have buffered. If the application calls io_func more than once, then the application may be discarding data read from the network. Fix by creating a single bufio.Reader outside the function and pass that single reader to each invocation of io_func.

Always check and handle errors. The error returned from any of these functions may point you in the right direction for a fix.

```
func io_func(r *bufio.Reader, conn net.Conn, cmd string) (string, error) {
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, cmd+"\n")
    header, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    if header == "SUCCESS\n" {
        return r.ReadString('\n')
    }
    return "", nil
}


...

r := bufio.NewReader(conn)

body, err := io_func(r, conn, cmd)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
var obvs []Json_out
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &obvs)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fmt.Println(body)
fmt.Println(obvs)

// read next 
body, err = io_func(r, conn, cmd)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

The application uses newline to terminate the JSON body, but newline is valid whitespace in JSON.  If the peer includes a newline in the JSON, then the application will read a partial message.

Comment: Thankyou, although not a solution in itself this led me to the correct answer and, I hope, improved my practice with bufio.Readers and error handling.